# string array contain duplicate value and remove and print the array

Tags: java, arrays, string

Sorry to Ask this question Again i had found alot in forum.But as of new to java am Excepting with Explanation  code i tried in my way  but it not working .i tried without any default method the code have to work for this program

Code:

```
    package javatest;

public class Test03sep {

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
                        //0   1            2    3
        String []val={"amma","senthil","kumar","amma"};
        removeduplicate(val);
    }
    static void removeduplicate(final String []arr)
    {

        String temp="";
             for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
             {
            for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) 
             {
                System.out.print("condition are:");
                 System.out.println(arr[i]==arr[j]);

                 if(arr[i]==arr[j])
                     {
                     temp=arr[i];
                     arr[i]=arr[j];
                     arr[j]=temp;

                     }

        }
            for (String string : arr) {
                System.out.println("string array are==>"+string);
            }
}
    }
}
```

output:

```
condition are:false
condition are:false
condition are:true
string array are==>amma
string array are==>senthil
string array are==>kumar
string array are==>amma
condition are:false
condition are:false
string array are==>amma
string array are==>senthil
string array are==>kumar
string array are==>amma
condition are:false
string array are==>amma
string array are==>senthil
string array are==>kumar
string array are==>amma
string array are==>amma
string array are==>senthil
string array are==>kumar
string array are==>amma
```

But i am Excepting the output are `String array are===>{"amma","senthil","kumar"};`

could some one can guide on this please????

Comment: `for (String string : arr) {
    System.out.println("string array are==>"+string);
 }`
If you are using an IDE, try to debug this code and see what happens when it executes the above code.

Comment: Just FYI, if you want to exclusively work with items without duplicates, you could look at java `Set` class.

Comment: @vikingsteve   my goal here to achieve without use a Default method like equals,contain,set,treeset...etc ...how to avoid and over come for my solution

Answer (score 0):

Please change `if(arr[i]==arr[j])` to  `if(arr[i].equals(arr[j]))`

While comparing string objects you should use `equals()` method instead of `"=="`

Comment: no i am trying  without Default method which are available in IDE.so without Equals how can i compare the value in java

Comment: Convert it to a `char[]` and compare each character? Odd design choice to do it without `.equals()`

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct as this is doing a memory comparison :

```
                 if(arr[i]==arr[j])
                 {
                   temp=arr[i];
                   arr[i]=arr[j];
                   arr[j]=temp;
                 }
```

Change it too this code to do value comparison:

```
                 if(arr[i].equals(arr[j]))
                 {
                   temp=arr[i];
                   arr[i]=arr[j];
                   arr[j]=temp;

                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if(arr[i]==arr[j]) replace to if(arr[i].equals(arr[j])) because == match hashcode of objects while equals() method is overrided in string and it match string char by char so use equals() methos instead of == operator

Comment: my goal here to achieve without use a Default method like equals,contain ...how to avoid and over come for my solution

Comment: you can use string getChars() method than match every character with another string character